# Can't pass char*** as argument

Tags: c, string, malloc

It's easy to see what am trying to accomplish here. read the list of files and pass it to another function.
Why this doesn't work. 
when i try to store the filenames in a local char**, it works just fine, but can't send it back via the pointer. Gives segmentation fault.

```
int main(){
    char** fileList;
    int noOfFiles;
    char* path = ".";
    makeList(&fileList, &noOfFiles, path); 
    return 0;
}

void makeList(char ***fileList, int* noOfFiles, char* path){
    struct dirent **fileListTemp;
    *noOfFiles = scandir(path, &fileListTemp, NULL, alphasort);
    int i;
    fileList = malloc(sizeof(char***));
    *fileList = malloc(sizeof(char**));
    printf("total: %d files",*noOfFiles);
    for(i = 0; i < *noOfFiles; i++){
        printf("%s\n",fileListTemp[i] -> d_name);   //works just fine
    }

    *fileList = malloc(*noOfFiles * sizeof(char*));
    for(i=0; i < *noOfFiles; i++){
        //*fileList[i] = fileListTemp[i] -> d_name;   this didn't work either...
        strcpy(*fileList[i], fileListTemp[i]->d_name);
        printf("%s\n", *fileList[i]);
    }
    //fileList = &list;
    return;
}
```

segmentation fault always...
and no hope of printing the fileList from main()

Comment: remove parameter `int aFlag` or add it to the call. The pointer `&fileList` won't exist after the function call, so assigning to it is not a good idea.

Comment: assigning it isn't a good idea? Storing the fileList in a local char** and returning it's pointer to main worked. But I don't understand why...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you overwrite the pointer to your `char** fileList`, which might be one problem:

```
 fileList = malloc(sizeof(char***));
```

Here you overwrite a previously allocated pointer, which looks like another problem:

```
 *fileList = malloc(*noOfFiles * sizeof(char*));
```